# In Unity know which button is clicked

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have two buttons create and join. Both button's on click event I move to next scene, but in next scene I have two scripts networkmanager and networkclient.

Now if I press create button I want to call only networkmanger not networkclient. So how can I disable the networkclient script and join I want to disabled networkmanger?

How can I know which button is been pressed?

Comment: Do you use Unity UI? If yes, you can add your spesific gameobject/script to button's listener.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void OnPress(){
   string name = this.gameObject.name;
   switch(name){
       case "Create":break;
       case "Join":break;
   }
}
```

You can read the name of the object the script is attached to.

If this is not suitable for any given reason (both scripts are on same object), you can pass a parameter to the method.

```
public void OnPress(string name){
   switch(name){
       case "Create":break;
       case "Join":break;
   }
}
```

then you give the name in the inspector.

The final way is to use two different methods for each button.

Comment: yes got this in case create if I want to disabled a script networkclient then what to do that script resides in my next scene public networkClient netclient; netclient.enabled=false; is not working

Comment: You would have to save the value, most likely using PlayerPrefs.

Comment: ok but I am new in unity if you have code or any tutorial than it would help me thanks

Comment: Check the docs on it http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html. It is fairly easy to use.